# The completion of $C_c(\mathbb{R}^k)$ with $\|f - g\|_p$ as a metric

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, lp-spaces, complete-spaces

In Rudin RCA, 3.15, he remarks that because $C_c(\mathbb{R}^k)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^k)$ (i.e. every point of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^k)$ is either in or a limit point of $C_c(\mathbb{R}^k)$) and because $L^p(\mathbb{R}^k)$ is a complete metric space, $L^p(\mathbb{R}^k)$ is *the* completion of $C_c(\mathbb{R}^k)$.  My question is, is this completion of a metric space unique, because he uses the word "the". In other words is the completion of $C_c(\mathbb{R}^k)$ necessarily $L^p(\mathbb{R}^k)$?

Comment: Lebesgue measure weirdness makes me think the answer is no, because two functions in an $L^p$ space would be equal _almost everywhere_, but that they wouldn't be equal as actual functions . . .

Comment: There are various ways of forming the completion so it is not correct to say 'the' completion. However, any two completions are isomorphic. Since the $L^p$ equivalence classes of elements of $C_c$ form a dense subset of $L_p$ (which is complete), it is in some sense a 'natural' completion.